# How can I write into Excel cells iteratively in Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am a newbie in programming and am trying to finish my first little project.

How can I write into Excel cells in Python iteratively?  I have tried `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl, xlsxwriter

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("link\\myworkbook.xls")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for iterated_value in range (2, ws.max_row):
    ws.cell(row = iterated_value, row = 4).value = value_to_write # value from elsewhere
```

but I am getting the error that I cannot use string for cell reference but number.  Also `xlsxwriter` (`ws` as above):

```
for iterated_value in range (2, ws.max_row):
    ws.write(iterated_value, 4, value_to_write)
```

with no success.

Comment: For openpyxl example you use row attribute twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
for iterated_value in range (2, ws.max_row): ws.cell(row = iterated_value, row = 4).value = value_to_write # value from elsewhere
```

in ws.cell() you use row 2 times, my guess is the second one should be column :)

Do you want to update an existing excelsheet or do you want to write a complete new excelsheet via python? If the second option applies: consider moving over to pandas and use dataframes